# How to print value of SimpleXmlElement Object

Tags: php, simplexml

I am getting a SimpleXML object back from a server using Guzzle. The response printed as string looks like valid XML. But when I try to get the individual element values, I am getting blank.

Please help me find what the problem is.

My code is here as well as on [Viper-7](http://viper-7.com/LFjfEU):

```
<?php
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RespOrderHistory xmlns="http://www.example.com/testService/xsd/OrderHistoryResponse_v1.xsd" xmlns:typ="http://www.example.com/testService/xsd/Types_v1.xsd">
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Cancelled</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Cancelled</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Cancelled</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Cancelled</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Cancelled</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>638</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-08T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>138</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-07T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-07T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>133</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-07T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-07T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
  <OrdersList>
    <typ:OrderNumber>128</typ:OrderNumber>
    <typ:OrderSubmitDate>2014-04-07T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:OrderSubmitDate>
    <typ:CurrentStatus>Active</typ:CurrentStatus>
    <typ:StatusDate>2014-04-07T00:00:00.000+05:30</typ:StatusDate>
  </OrdersList>
</RespOrderHistory>';

$sXml = simplexml_load_string ($xml);

foreach($sXml as $order){
    echo $order->getName()." ";
    print_r($order);
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: you may have to spell out namespaces when calling `simplexml_load_string`. See [these docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php), especially the `ns` and `is_prefix` parameters.

Comment: @collapsar - tried but couldn't do it. http://viper-7.com/aOjiAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: By putting your code into your question, you will make it easier for others to help you.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
```

You will need **2** nested loops to iterate. First, you will want to select the `<OrdersList>`-nodes correctly, see the outer loop.

```
foreach ($xml->OrdersList as $orders) {
```

The children of `<OrdersList>` are `namespaced`:
`$order->OrderNumber` doesn't work, but the `children()`-method does the job:

```
    foreach ($orders->children("typ", TRUE) as $name => $value) {

        echo "$name: $value <br />";

    }

}
```

see it working: http://viper-7.com/bS2pEJ

Recommended reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Comment: I already have put the code in the question since the begining. It's just that the xml is huge that the code stays hidden at the bottom.

Thanks for the help and that solved the problem

Comment: @Srihari oh sorry, I didn't scroll down.